# How do I loop through the interface implementing Classes (and call interface methods of the class) that I have fetched through Refections in Java?

Tags: java, loops, generics, reflection, interface

I have tried to fetch a Set of Classes that **implements** an interface `IDispatchIdsReplaceable` using `Refections`. Now what I want to do is loop through these classes, call the interface method (overridden methods) within the loop and perform the implementations. How can I do this?

Pseudo Code:

```
public interface IDispatchIdsReplaceable {
    void replace();
}

public class Class1 implements IDispatchIdsReplaceable  {
//usual class methods

@Override
void replace() {
//implementation
}

}

public class Class2 implements IDispatchIdsReplaceable  {
//usual class methods

@Override
void replace() {
//implementation
}

}
```

In some other method, this function is needed

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.company");
Set<Class<? extends IDispatchIdsReplaceable>> classesImplementingIDispatchIdsReplaceable = reflections.getSubTypesOf(IDispatchIdsReplaceable.class);

for (Class<? extends IDispatchIdsReplaceable> classImplementingInterface : classesImplementingIDispatchIdsReplaceable) {
    //classImplementingInterface.replace(); -> basically somthing like Class1.replace() or Class2.replace() along with the loop.
    //How to do the above sort of function call and run those overriden methods of the respective class
}
```

It gives me error when i run `classImplementingInterface.replace()` in the loop

```
Cannot resolve method 'replace' in 'Class'
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is missing here is that `replace` method should be called from an instance, so you need first to create an instance of that class and then call `replace`:

```
for (Class<? extends IDispatchIdsReplaceable> classImplementingInterface : classesImplementingIDispatchIdsReplaceable) {
    IDispatchIdsReplaceable instance = classImplementingInterface.getConstructor().newInstance(); // Choose the right constructor, here I'm using the default one
    instance.replace();  
}
```

**EDIT:**

The default constructor should be implemented explicitly inside your subclasses or you will get `NoSuchMethodException`

Comment: Won't different classes have different constructors? Also, I tried the way you suggested. It shows and error at .getConstructor() 
```Unhandled exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException``` @Ismail

Comment: Is the default constructor exists in your classes?

Comment: Yea I understand, but it shows error. Dont know why?

Comment: I've tried the same code locally and I've found the error, the default constructor should be implemented explicitly inside your subclasses. check the EDIT. Now it works with me.

Comment: I had to throw a ```throws NoSuchMethodException``` in the method containing reflection and the loops to get the error removed. But then having that sorted I am getting an error 
```Unhandled exceptions: java.lang.InstantiationException, java.lang.IllegalAccessException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException``` on the ```.newInstance()```. Is it how it is supposed to work? Do i need to throw them as well. For some reason doesn't seem right the throwing part. @ismail

Comment: Do i need to use try and catch?

Comment: You can use try and catch block to handle and customize yourself the exception message or throws those exceptions in the header of the method, but I think it's better to use try and catch block.

Comment: Have you any other issues or this solution work well? If you see think that this answers your question don't forget to check it as the right answer.